# ListFragment called from Button

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-button, android-listfragment

This batch of code will place a ListFragment into a LinearLayout that I have selected, and it works fine. The problem I have is that this initiates from onCreate and I would like it to trigger from a Button.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    TamInputListFragment lstfragment=(TamInputListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("lstfragment");
    if(lstfragment==null){
        lstfragment=new TamInputListFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transact=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transact.add(R.id.fragment_container,lstfragment,"lstfragment");
        transact.commit();

    }
```

This batch of code worked for a previous tutorial that just interchanged two simple Fragment with two separate Button.

```
public void selectFrag(View view){
    Fragment fr;

    if (view == findViewById(R.id.button2)) {
        fr = new FragmentTwo();
    }
    else {
        fr = new FragmentOne();
    }
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

But when I use this same batch of code and swap out FragmentOne() and FragmentTwo() for the two new ListFragment classes that I have made, TamInputListFragment and VerbInputListFragment, I get an "Incompatible Type" error saying that is wants a android.app.Fragment and not a com.example.petakirikiri.fragmenttest.Fragments.TamInputListFragment();

```
public void selectFrag(View view){
    Fragment fr;

    if (view == findViewById(R.id.verb_button) {
        fr = new TamInputListFragment();
    }
    else {
        fr = new VerbInputListFragment();
    }
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fr);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: What would you like to have happen? What is happening instead?

Comment: I would like the fragment_container to be filled with the TamInputListFragment or the VerbInputListFragment which are both of type ListFragment. I get an "Incompatible Type" error saying that is wants a android.app.Fragment and not a com.example.petakirikiri.fragmenttest.Fragments.TamInputListFragment();